# I get this error after update my flutter version to latest version (2.10)

Tags: flutter

Guys please help me i can't build or upgrade anything in flutter and i get alot of errors like that FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Carnival.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\625039eaad011f884ddd84f857a44b7f\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle
> aar-metadata.properties.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Carnival.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a78fdf90e4c1f8464b19895cfb365f3f\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-m
> etadata.properties.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: run flutter ocker and see whats the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in build.gradle file.

`(YourAppName\android\build.gradle).`

**compileSdkVersion** from 29 to 30

**targetSdkVersion** from 29 to 30

If you're already in version 30 then check yourappname/android/build.gradle has these repositories or not

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
             }allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}}rootProject.buildDir = '../build'subprojects {
project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')}task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

**This above code is not beautiful as StackOverflow is not able to take build.gradle file**

Answer (score 0):

30 might also fail so just bump it up to 31 also, the **ext.kotlin_version** might also cause problems after the above change and will need the latest version which is **1.6.10**. However, implement the changes as necessary. If changing the SdkVersion alone solves your problem, call it a win.

Comment: If it's not a bother, you could upvote